# IFS to read systeminfos

Tags: bash, ifs

I tried to read some system infos and put them into variables:

```
df -k | grep /dev/mmcblk0p1 | IFS=" " read -r device blocks used available use_percent mounted_on
```

It did not work, all variables are empty.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the IFS, it's because in bash (and certain other shells) the RHS of a pipeline is executed in a subshell.

A simple alternative is to use process substitution to keep the `read` in the parent shell:

```
read -r device blocks used available use_percent mounted_on < <(df -k | grep /dev/mmcblk0p1)
```

See [Bash: Variable assignment doesn't seem to 'stick'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155607/bash-variable-assignment-doesnt-seem-to-stick)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign variables using `read`, these must be part of the same block statement `{ ... }`:

```
 df -k | grep /dev/mmcblk0p1 | { 
   read -r device blocks used available use_percent mounted_on
   printf "device=%s\nblocks=%s\nused=%s\navailable=%s\nuse_percent=%s\nmounted_on=%s\n" $device $blocks $used $available $use_percent $mounted_on
}
```